# How to upload a word document and find duplicate values in that document using PHP

Tags: php

How to upload a word document and find duplicate values in that document using PHP.

Comment: Have you tried? Can you post what didn't work?

Comment: I can able to read the uploaded file. But can't able to find the duplicate values

Comment: can you please be more specific about what exactly are you looking for? Duplicate lines/words/pages?

Comment: duplicate words... If i have "TEST" three times and "TEST1" for two times in the doc then the o/p should return "3 duplicate values in TEST" , "2 duplicate values in TEST1"

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I can think of would be to import the word DOC using Antiword as demonstrated here: http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php. Once you have the file contents you should be able to check for redundancy in many different ways. For example, you could use PHP's strtok function to tokenize and index the words and then look for redundancies in the array. I'm sure once you have the content of the document, finding duplicates won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
$array_val = explode(',',$theData);
$len = count($array_val);

for($t=0;$t<$len;$t++)
{
    for($i=$t+1;$i<$len;$i++)
    {   
        if(($array_val[$t]==$array_val[$i]))
        {
            $new_arr[]=$array_val[$t]; 
            break;
        }
    }}

print_r(array_unique($new_arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) theres a class written for it at http://drewd.com/2007/01/25/reading-from-a-word-document-with-com-in-php